# How can I use output of a python script for a zap trigger?

Tags: python, zapier

I have a simple script shown below. I want to use the value of holiday_value to create a filter. I am thinking this could be done by putting the value into zap storage and then retrieving the value from storage and use it in a zap filter. I don't know how to get the value from the script into zap storage.

```
from datetime import date
import holidays

us_holidays = holidays.US()

if date.today() in us_holidays:
    holiday_value='true'

else:
    holiday_value='false'
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really good at Python, but here's what you could do.

#### Trigger

If you want to trigger another Zap from this Code step, you could use the [requests library](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/) and Zapier's [Webhooks](https://zapier.com/help/webhooks/) as a Trigger step for your other Zap (Zap that you want to Trigger).

Here are the steps:

1. Setup a Zap with the trigger app as Webhooks. Get the webhook URL.
2. From the Code step, make a request to the Webhook URL with the value of `holiday_value`. (Here is a [sample POST request](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#more-complicated-post-requests)). Also helpful to refer to [this example](https://zapier.com/help/code-python/#introductory-http-example).

#### Filter

If you are looking for creating a filter in the same Zap instead,
You could return the value of `holiday_value` from this code step. Refer documentation [here](https://zapier.com/help/code-python/#introductory-examples).

Your code would probably look like (Please check syntax, I'm not good at Python),

```py
from datetime import date
import holidays

us_holidays = holidays.US()

if date.today() in us_holidays:
    return {'holiday_value': 'true'}

else:
    return {'holiday_value': 'false'}
```

You can now add a filter step that only allows the Zap to continue if `holiday_value` equals `True` or `False`. Documentation for filters [here](https://zapier.com/help/filter/).

Hope that helps.